# ggplot2 - color intensity (Transparent to deep) for single color in a multi color plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the [data](https://app.box.com/s/r496rmnffmmv35f8lebnb1n1s3p7upk7)

Then assign above data under a variable "mydata"

```
mydata <- mydata
library(ggplot2)
p<- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=tSNE_1,y=tSNE_2)) +
geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cluster), shape = variable)) 
print(p)
```

Then we the the following output
[ggplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LdNb.png)

Now our data structure is

```
> head(mydata)
       tSNE_1      tSNE_2 cluster variable value
1  -1.0794380 -15.2732678       3    Pde1a     1
2   2.5828641 -14.8813390       3    Pde1a     0
3  -6.9095978  -9.5625352       1    Pde1a     0
4   5.4793466   7.3691444       0    Pde1a     3
5 -10.6781109 -11.5297445       1    Pde1a     0
6   0.5156696   0.5353185       1    Pde1a     0
```

Now the above image has different color based on "cluster".

But I want to plot same image as above but with cluster color intensity (Transparent [min] to Deep [max] color) based on "value". How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: add `alpha = value` within the call to `aes` in your `geom_point`. e.g. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp))+
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(am), alpha = gear))`

Comment: Thanks !! it works instantly. can you tell me how to scale data so that , low value become more low and high value become more high to get better isolation ?

Comment: You would be better off consulting [this ggplot2 help page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_alpha.html)

Comment: Your answer is really helpful !! Thanks a lot .